# text-overflow: ellipsis isn't working-why?

Tags: html, css

This overflow ellipsis doesn't seem to be working and it looks like documentation examples what am I doing wrong?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adqxbq9x/22/)

```css
p {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  word-break: break-all;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p>
  sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
</p>
```

Comment: This doesn’t work in combination with `word-break: break-all` ... in fact, in most browsers this currently only works for single-line content.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing `white-space: nowrap;` also `word-break: break-all` isn't necessary in this case.

```css
p{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p>
Some long text it is going to be ellipsed 
</p>
```

---

if you are going to have a long word without spaces then you don't even need  `white-space: nowrap;`

```css
p{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p>
sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using text-overflow: ellipsis; for dotted if width overflow the width and white-space: nowrap; without using nowrap "dotted effect will not work"

```css
p{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
```